# Do I have to verify JWT for every api calls?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am making a simple project for practicing django.

I used simplejwt to implement the auth process with JWT.

Also, I have React frontend environment and making API calls using axios, but there are some questions:

Do I have to verify JWT for every API call?

And which is the better way to verify the token:
Making an API request from the client(frontend) to "api/token/verify/" with token, or designing every API starting from calling its verifying API on the server-side(but it seems a little weird because every API need to require the token additionally)?

For instance, if I write a comment and click the submit button, the former does call the token verifying API before calling the writing API on the client side(React), while the latter only calls the writing API but the API itself calls the verifying API before handling its own API logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in essence, never trust the client ever ever ever.

Answer (score 0):

On whichever API you want to have auth, you need to verify your JWT token, because if you don't verify the JWT token, how would the backend know this is an authorized user to perform the transaction? You don't need to verify JWT on your frontend client, your backend can do this for your, you need to pass your token in request headers, and in the backend, you can have middleware or some decorator which will be responsible for verification of user.